# writing to variable filename

Tags: c++, filenames, fstream, ofstream

I want to write to different files with names give by variable r. Following is what I wrote. The proble here is, it is just opening the first file 'r=0.5.txt' and writing on it the data for r=0.5. However, it does not open and write on other files with r=0.6, 1.0...
edit: added Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <sstream>

using namespace std; 





int main()

{   //initialization
int M = 5; //no. of steps
double rvalues[] = {0.5,1.5,8.,15.,24.5};
double x,y,z,r;
//initial condition fixed pnts x*,y*,z*= (0,0,0)
double x0 =  1.5;
double y0 =  1.5;
double z0 = 1.5; 
ofstream myfile;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeof(rvalues)/sizeof(rvalues[0]);i++){
    r = rvalues[i];
    x = x0;
    y = y0;
    z=z0;
    stringstream ss;
    cout<<"ravlues = "<<r<<endl;
    ss<<"r="<<r<<".txt";
    string filename = ss.str();
    cout<<filename<<endl;
    myfile.open(filename.c_str());
    for(int j = 0; j<M;j++){
        myfile<<x<<'\t'<<y<<'\t'<<z<<'\n';

        x =x+j;
        y = y+j;
        z = z+j;
    }
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: ah i did mistake while posting the question, it should be `int rvalues[] = {..}`

Comment: Do you realise `rvalues` really gets initialized to `{0, 0, 1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: Post a complete example that actually compiles (with properly declared variables and real comments, for instance) and you'll have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's so much easier to figure out where a problem is from an MCVE than trying to guess where the problem could be from bits and pieces of code.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry, I didn't catch that. what do you mean by it gets initialized to `{0,0,1,2,3}`?

Comment: I mean those are the values the `rvalues` array holds after initialization. You can trivially check that with some code.

Comment: @RSahu added MCVE, can you comment on it now..

Comment: @jason You should test results of `myfile.open(filename.c_str());` using some statement like `if(!myfile) { /* error */ }`

Comment: @juanchopanza oh, I got what you meant, but only for earlier example I mistakenly wrote `int rvalues[]={...}` but actually it is `double ravlues[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `myfile.close()` at the end of the loop. It will be easier if you define `myfile` in the scope of the `for` loop.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeof(rvalues)/sizeof(rvalues[0]);i++){
    r = rvalues[i];
    x = x0;
    y = y0;
    z=z0;
    stringstream ss;
    cout<<"ravlues = "<<r<<endl;
    ss<<"r="<<r<<".txt";
    string filename = ss.str();
    cout<<filename<<endl;

    ofstream myfile(filename.c_str());  // Move it inside the loop.

    for(int j = 0; j<M;j++){
        myfile<<x<<'\t'<<y<<'\t'<<z<<'\n';

        x =x+j;
        y = y+j;
        z = z+j;
    }
}
```